# C# - Entity type (entity) not part of model for current context error in Windows Form Application with SQL Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a project that involves simply filling out a string of textboxes and clicking a button that will add the values in the textboxes to their respective variables in a new instance of a class, and save this instance of the class in a database.

I created the database first of all and used Entity Frameworks to create the class from it, so I know they are linked to eachother.
The general code for my class is shown below:

```
public partial class AnaestheticRecord
{
    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Owner_Name { get; set; }
//25 other attributes of class
...
    //methods------------------------------------------------
    //get number of instances of class (objects + 1 creates new PatientID)

    private static int objects = 0;

    public AnaestheticRecord()
    {
        ++objects; //add one to count
    }

    ~AnaestheticRecord()
    {
        --objects; //remove one from count
    }

    public static int getPatientID()
    {
        objects += 1;   //add 1 more to create previously unused value
        return objects; //return new value
    }
```

So, when it came time to add the code to make the application function, I started by declaring new instances of the class displayed above, and of the Entities class that should allow access to the database...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    //empty instance of class, each property takes data through console input
    AnaestheticRecord aRecord = new AnaestheticRecord(); //create new instance of anaesthetic record class ready for data input
    List<AnaestheticRecord> recordCollection = new List<AnaestheticRecord>(); //create list to store instances of anaesthetic records (display-record purposes)
    BlueBookDBEntities db = new BlueBookDBEntities(); //create entities to run database
```

This all works fine, but once the series of textboxes has been filled out and the button is clicked to add this record to the datase, the following code is run and an error is produced:

```
    private void btnSaveRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //transfer and convert values from input to respective field in record
        addToClass();
        recordCollection.Add(aRecord); //add completed instance of class to list
        db.TblAnaestheticRecords.Add(aRecord); //add completed anaesthetic record to database (ERROR)
        db.SaveChanges(); //save new input to database
    }
```

At this point, the line 'db.TblAnaestheticRecords.Add(aRecord)' throws an error stating that "Entity type AnaestheticRecord is not part of model for current context".

I'm a little stuck here, as I can't see what I've done wrong. I've done this kind of thing before using MVC where slightly more of the groundwork is done for you, but this is my first time using a database linked to a Windows Form Application.
If anyone could point out to me where I've gone wrong, and maybe point me in the right direction as to how to get past this error, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

In the context you need to insert also the AnaestheticRecord DbSet (all the related tables, 1 DbSet for relational table)

Comment: Thanks for this, does the context need to go at the end of the class?

Comment: Following on from your reply earlier, I tried to add the DbSet by adding the following to the end of the AnaestheticRecord class:

`public class AnaestheticRecordDBContext : DbContext
      {
          public DbSet<AnaestheticRecord> Records { set; get; }
      }`

This has led to no success. As the class was created from the database will there already be an existing context elsewhere?
Thanks
@bubi

Comment: The context is BlueBookDBEntities. With DbFirst approach usually is ok but check it becouse usually that's the reason of your error.